# Linking to pub/media from Extension

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, magento2.2, phtml, media-images

I'm trying to link to pub/media product images from inside an extension's .phtml so I can reuse them rather than duplicate them inside the extension. I tried...

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog/product/t/e/')?>test.jpg"/>
```

For some reason it strips the "e/" when I view the source...

```
<img src="http://dev:8888/pub/media/catalog/product/t/test.jpg">
```

If I move test.jpg to "product/t" it works, but I need to access them from the correct location. I'm currently using Magento 2.1.9 but will be upgrading to 2.2 soon.

Comment: Are you fetching product image dynamically? I mean to say from product object?

Comment: No. I just want to link to images from within the .phtml as easily as I could from within the module. I found this as a working solution <img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/myfolder/")?>image.png"/> but in my case the last folder is stripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                        ->getStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

<img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'myfolder/image.png';?>"/>
```

Above is not standard way as per magento standard use below code above code just for your quick feasibility test purpose

In your respected block of phtml file add below code:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct( 
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getMediaUrl()
{
    $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager
                     ->getStore()
                     ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    return $mediaUrl;
}
```

add below code to your phtml file:

```
<?php $mediUrl = $block->getMediaUrl(); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $mediUrl.'myfolder/image.png';?>"/>
```

Comment: The top example works great, thanks. The 2nd example is returning HTTP ERROR 500. Could you also please tell me briefly the reason why all this is needed for something as simple as getting the URL of the media folder to help me understand. It seems like overkill.

Comment: can you please add your block code in question

Comment: Sorry, have I misunderstood this line "In your respected block of phtml file add below code"? I've included all the code at the top of my main.phtml  file. Should the "protected $_storeManager;" code go somewhere else? The 1st example worked fine in the .phtml.

Comment: yes that code you need to add in your block file

Comment: I've just created Block/Display.php and put your code in. Then in view/frontend/layout I've added a new XML file. Inside the referenceContainer I've added <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Display" name="images_from_media" template="Vendor_Module::main.phtml" />. On the page where the image should appear the $mediUrl part of the path is missing.

Comment: Which path is missing?

Comment: I gave up because my extension development experience is not in-depth enough and I was creating more problems. I also tried using a Helper without success. I've got in to work with <?php $url = $block->getBaseUrl(); ?><img src="<?php echo $url ?>pub/media/catalog/product/t/e/test.jpg" />  which isn't very elegant but at least I can link to the images.

Comment: Would you be able to give me the missing steps so I could use your way please? I added the code the phtml and created Block/getimages.php containing the block php code. What I had problems with is the layout xml. I assume that is the only bit I was missing?

Comment: you need to add this code in your respected layout file: <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Display" name="images_from_media" template="Vendor_Module::main.phtml" />  add this code in template file where you want to call image $this->getChildHtml(images_from_media);

Comment: I've accepted the answer for the first method but I couldn't get the 2nd example to work. There is obviously a problem with the layout XML because I'm getting a 500 error. I found the referenceContainer name with the hints enabled but something isn't right. The method using getBaseUrl is working so I'll stick with that.